# Graphql Mutation with Array types

Tags: angular, graphql, symfony4, apollo-client, graphiql

I'm trying to write a mutation query and it works perfectly with graphql

```
mutation($project: ProjectsInput) {
  NewProject(project: $project) {
    name,
    namespace,
    environments{
      env,      
    }}}
```

these are the query variables

```
{"project": {
   "name": "Pr1",
  "namespace": "Pr2",
  "environments": 

  [{"env": "rec"},{"env": "dev"}]


}}
```

and this is how it looks 
[graphql mutation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpuK4.png)
now I am trying to use Apollo Client in angular to build this mutation like so

```
    createProject() {
    this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: gql`
      mutation($project: ProjectsInput) {
        NewProject(project: $project) {
          name,
          namespace,
          environments{
            env,      
          }
    `,
      variables: { 
        project: {
          name: "sth",
          namespace: "sth2",
          env: [
            {env:"env1"},
            {env:"env2"}
          ]
        } 
      }
    }).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('New project created!', data);

    });  }
```

But i'm getting Http failure response because of the variable $env of type Array.i want to pass an array as a variable for the query in apollo client.I don't have problems with variables of type string but the array objects causes this error.

Comment: use graphiql docs to check mutation signature - probably ONE input variable - pass all data as one input object (matching one input variable), try with graphiql using `query variables` (below query) ... then use code (apollo-client)

Comment: thank you for your reply, actually i tried with TWO input variables and it worked fine. The problem is that i'm stack with the  array list type. i want to dynamically persist that array of objects. regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NewProject(project:` shows that your `NewProject` mutation needs one `project` parameter

change query to

```
mutation($project: ProjectsInput) {
  NewProject(project: $project) {
    name,
    namespace,
    environments{
      env,      
    }
```

and pass one, entire object to variable `project`

**use `query variables` in `graphiql` to define test variables:**

```
{ 
  project: {
    name: "sth",
    namespace: "sth2",
    environments: [
      {env:"env1"},
      {env:"env2"}
    ]
  } 
}
```

then in client prepare the same kind of object for `project` variable (with structure matching your mutation input type, of course).

Comment: Thank you sir but that's not the problem.The query works fine. The problem is that  the size of the array 'env' is not static (a project has many environments fixed by the admin) . string variables does not cause a problem. in this case when i remove $env variable from apollo request it works fine but when i add the array i get an error.

Comment: show your mutation signature - from graphiql ... and input types definitions used in this mutation

Comment: i have edited the post. what i want to do is to add an array of objects to the apollo client request.regards

Comment: nothing changed .... only we know input type name ;) `ProjectsInput`, still prepare ONE object, try first in graphiql (using query variables!! not hardcoding structures and passing subproperties ), then recreate in code

Comment: i did what you have told me and i edited once again the post. i'm using query variables now like in the picture(edited in the post). the problem is actually not in the backend Api but in the apollo client request. i hope i'm understanding what you are trying to tell me. thanks

Comment: just try to create some `project` object (with all required subproperties) from code before passing it as project to variables ... sadly it's angular ;)

Comment: i'm getting this error "Syntax Error: Expected Name, found <EOF>"

Comment: you can try to prepare entire `variables` object, `console.log()` it before passing to mutation ... you can also inspect network request body using browser dev tools

Comment: ... because it's name is `environments` ?  .... `"namespace":"sth2",    >>>"environments" <<<   :[{"env":"env1"}`